# Why Architecture menu in visual studio 2012 Premium does not work

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Architecture menu in visual studio 2012 Premium does not work. It is showing me in disable mode.I checked in customize menu but toolbar added in Disable form. I can not generate the "Visualize Code Dependencies on Dependency Graphs".

Is there any option without upgrading Visual studio 2012 from Premium to Ultimate  Architecture menu work.?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is an Ultimate only tool.

Answer (score 0):

Architecture menu in Visual Studio show only with Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate edition.To use this option/feature need to buy Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate edition.